# Javascript array - element access

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have

```
    var prosjeci = [];
    var parametar = $("#parametar1").val();
```

Function for getting data from server:

```
    function podatciPrethodniDan()
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "php/getPreviousDayData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {parametar: parametar },
          success: function(data) 
          {                         
            obradiPodatkePrehtodnogDana(data);
          }//end of success
        });//end of ajax
    }
```

Function which fill array with data:

```
    function obradiPodatkePrehtodnogDana(data)
    {
        var stanica1Prosjek = 0;
        var stanica2Prosjek = 0;
        var stanica3Prosjek = 0;
        var stanica4Prosjek = 0;

        console.log(data);

        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            if(i<24)
            {
                stanica1Prosjek = stanica1Prosjek + parseFloat(data[i].par);
            }
            else if(i>=24 && i<48)
            {
                stanica2Prosjek += parseFloat(data[i].par); 
            }
            else if(i>=48 && i<72)
            {
                stanica3Prosjek += parseFloat(data[i].par); 
            }
            else
            {
                stanica4Prosjek += parseFloat(data[i].par);
            }
        }

        prosjeci.push(stanica1Prosjek/24);
        prosjeci.push(stanica2Prosjek/24);
        prosjeci.push(stanica3Prosjek/24);
        prosjeci.push(stanica4Prosjek/24);
    }
```

Results of console.log(data): 
(only first elment)

```
 Array[96]
 0:Object
   datum:"2016-10-31"
   par:"60"
   stanica"1"
```

Call function

```
    podatciPrethodniDan();
```

Print out array:

```
    console.log(prosjeci);
    console.log(prosjeci[0]);
```

I get all data succesfull and i fill array sucessfull but i can't to access array element.

Results of first console.log:

```
Array[4]
0:60.44999999999999
1:76.41666666666667
2:85.3875
3:82.47083333333335
length:4
```

Results of second console.log:

```
undefined
```

I cant access arrays element?

Comment: Do share a fiddle of the same...

Comment: No makes sense, there are more code or details?

Comment: I use ajax and localhost , i cant use fiddle

Comment: I will add whole code

Comment: I'm guessing that you're logging the array before it's populated, then expanding it afterwards.  Are you in Chrome - is there a little blue `i` next to the expanded object?

Comment: This is probably asynchronous code biting you in the behind. Can't really tell without seeing more code.

Comment: I added more code

Comment: are these strings that you have added to the array

Comment: can you also add the data that you are sending to the function obradiPodatkePrehtodnogDana

Comment: @Geeky No , these are not strings. I tried console.log(prosjeci[0].toString()); but i get  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(…)

Comment: @Geeky you want console.log of  parametar data ?

Comment: yes i want to see what are you sending the parameters to that function

Comment: Assuming your `console.log`s are immediately after the call to `podatciPrethodniDan`, my earlier guess was correct.  You're simply logging it before it's been populated, but the browser allows you to expand and re-evaluate the object at a later time.  Replace the calls to `console.log` with `console.dir` and you'll see that the array is empty at the point you log it.

Comment: Your overall problem is very similar to that described in [this canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: @JamesThorpe i replaced console.log with console.dir and i get same result. I will check your link

Comment: You will still get the `undefined` for the 2nd one, but if you do `console.dir(prosjeci);` you should see an empty array.

Comment: @JamesThorpe             No,  console.dir(prosjeci); and console.log(prosjeci); same result, i  checked twice :)

Comment: can you add the console.log(data) please

Comment: @Geeky console.log(data) added!

Comment: Ah - seems `console.dir` allows for later expansion as well, didn't think it did.  Your problem still remains the same though.  Read the Q&A I linked thoroughly.

Comment: I dont think your array has numbers as you have mentioned...it should be all 0's i guess ....

Comment: @Geeky i c/p results from console

Comment: is it solved? what happened here?please let us know how did you fix this

Comment: @Geeky Thanks for effort, solved by adding async: false at $.ajax

Comment: oh thats nice to hear